# Which combination of switch and if/else is faster and why?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, compiler-optimization

I have two sets of conditions. One has two possible values and the other has more (in this example I wrote 3 cases but there could be up to 8). Which code runs faster and is less error prompt (more accurate)?

code a)

```
if (letter.equals(a)) {
  switch (number) {

    case 1:
           .........
    case 2:
           .........
    case 3:
           .........
  }
} else if (letter.equals(b)) {
  switch (number) {

    case 1:
           .........
    case 2:
           .........
    case 3:
           .........
  }
}
```

code b)

```
switch (number) {

    case 1:

           if (letter.equals(a)) {
              .........
           } else if (letter.equals(b)) {
              .........
           }

    case 2:

           if (letter.equals(a)) {
              .........
           } else if (letter.equals(b)) {
              .........
           }

    case 3:

           if (letter.equals(a)) {
              .........
           } else if (letter.equals(b)) {
              .........
           }
  }
```

Please tell me if you think there is a better option other than these two. (I could also create a parameter that gets both `letter` and `number` and create 6 cases using that.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is opinion-based .. but I like a) more.

Comment: When you think about it, in both structures you'll have to go through an if/else and switch exactly once. Performance doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a micro-optimisation that probably has no effect on your code, so 'which is faster' doesn't really matter here.

If you want to find out which of a particular combination of cases *in your codebase* then you probably want to use a benchmarking tool like JMH to figure out which is more appropriate for you. But unless this code is on the critical path it won't make a difference.

Code needs to be:

1. Correct
2. Readable
3. Performant

It's much better to focus on 1 & 2 than the last.

In this particular case, a switch-over-numbers is probably faster for the JVM under the covers, while switch-over-expressions will naturally involve more jumping around in the branches. I would therefore naively expect switch-over-int-followed-by-if will marginally edge out the other way around, but without proof this would be a hunch and not something to rely on. It's also quite likely that whatever benchmark is written there will be some kind of flaws, such that the JVM is automatically promoting the optimal test case combination to the first test, in which case it won't tell you what you think it is doing.

Ultimately, write it for readability/maintainability rather than performance, until you can prove this is on the hot loop, and then measure it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> Which code runs faster and is less error prompt (more accurate)?

Answer: In this specific case performance is not the issue. Because no matter how you are going to use this actual execution numbers are same. But you can improve the code readability and making it less errorprone.

Instead of worrying about performance, start with SOLID principle. Why don't you just break this big method into some smaller method which has a concrete responsibility. It will make code more beautiful and less error prone. For example:

Methods:

```
void processA(int number){
switch (number) {

    case 1:
           .........
    case 2:
           .........
    case 3:
           .........
  }
}

void processB(int number){
    
  switch (number) {

    case 1:
           .........
    case 2:
           .........
    case 3:
           .........
  }
}

///
now from the main method you could simply call:


if (letter.equals(a)) {
   // call the method which will process A
   processA(number);
} else if (letter.equals(b)) {
   // call the method which will process A
   processB(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option:

```
    switch (String.format("%1s%1d", letter, number) {
        case "a1": 
            ...
        case "b1":
            ...
        case "a2"
            ...
        case "b2":
            ...
        case "a3":
            ...
        case "b3": 
            ...
    }
```

Better? Maybe, maybe not.  But it *is* an alternative...

Comment: I do kinda like this "trick" but it's important to note that it won't improve performance. It replaces an if/else + switch by a function-call + switch. There is essentially no difference.

Comment: Yeah, @akuzminykh I agree: performance-wise it's probably no better (but probably not much worse either).  Readability-wise, however, it's much better, especially if the simple example of "either 'a' or 'b' and either 1, 2, or 3" turned out in reality to be  "either 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'y' or 'z' and either 1, 2, 3,..., 49, or 50"!